# Some transactions don't run in db transaction

Tags: c#, transactions

I use transaction in my code. I haven't had any problems for a long time but there is a problem now. Transaction like this:

```
 using (var transaction = _myContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
 {
     try
     {
         _table1Repository.Update(table1Rec);

         _table2Repository.Insert(table2Rec);

         transaction.Commit();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         transaction.Rollback();
        // some code...
     }
 }
```

Table1 have a sub table by the way. My problem is: Sometimes Table1 is updated properly but its sub table don't update and table2Rec don't create. If there is an error, it should be go to rollback but sometimes it don't run rollback also don't do all process properly. What could be the cause of this problem?

--edit

Repository methods like this:

```
private readonly MyContext _context;
private DbSet<T> _entities;
 public MyRepository(MyContext context)
 {
     _context = context;
     _entities = context.Set<T>();
 }

public void Insert(T entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
   
    _entities.Add(entity);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}

 public void Update(T entity)
 {
     if (entity == null)
         throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));

     _entities.Update(entity);
     _context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Comment: how _table1Repository and _table2Repository knows anything about if you started a transation or not?

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik It is not a problem. I use same context in repository. I use hundreds transactions like this in this project and it works for years.

Comment: its the only problem you may have here. Either both of those repositories have its separate transactions, or they got no clue that you started one, or they handle their exceptions somewhere inside without throwing it to the caller. You need to post more code to help you out. Unfortunatelly i dont have my crystall ball with me today, so i cannot make predictions.

Comment: are you sure that `_myContext` is the same one as `_context` in both of your repositories?

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik yes

Comment: I suspect that the transaction cannot be performed on the SQL server side and no error is returned. But why might it be doing such a thing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256908/discussion-between-bartosz-olchowik-and-fatih).

Comment: This is not possible. Either the context is not the same, or there is a `catch` somewhere that is being swallowed. Side notes: there is no need for a transaction really, you are actually supposed to use `SaveChanges` as the transaction scope, it does transactions internally anyway. Also if you do have a transaction you don't need to `Rollback` manually if you have a `using` on it.

Comment: This is possible. Context is same. Problem is that cannot save entity but also not give an error and don't drop to catch. I've experienced something similar before. Index fragmantation was too high. I rebuild it and it was solved. I cannot find it this time. @Charlieface I also need transaction here. SaveChanges not enough in my cases. After table2Rec inserted I use its Id. I removed the code because of It is not important for our case.

Comment: `SaveChanges` doesn't swallow exceptions anywhere so you must have a `catch` *somewhere* that is swallowing it. Index fragmentation by itself shouldn't cause an error so not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: I know that index fragmentation by itself shouldn't cause an error. I want to say maybe it doesn't fall into the catch for a similar reason. I'm not sure there is an exception.

Comment: @Charlieface i have to disagree with you on what you said "Also if you do have a transaction you don't need to `Rollback` manually if you have a using on it".
Not on every database, maybe for MS SQL yes, but for ORACLE it depend on database configuration.

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik This is part of ADO.Net not a server-side transaction. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E85694_01/ODPNT/TransactionDispose.htm#GUID-6A14E889-D711-482B-8F81-8DC957204ECD says "If the transaction is not in a completed state, an attempt to rollback the transaction is made." this happens on `Dispose()`

Comment: @Charlieface aaa ok- yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You should start transaction from same context from where you are doing insert and update operations. I think you have shared your generic repository which you are implementing on table1 and table2 repository.

Create one method in your generic repository to begin transaction.

For example

**Generic Repository**

```
private readonly MyContext _context;
private DbSet<T> _entities;
public MyRepository(MyContext context)
{
    _context = context;
    _entities = context.Set<T>();
}

public IDbContextTransaction BeginTransaction()
{
    return _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
}

public void Insert(T entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));

    _entities.Add(entity);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}

public void Update(T entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));

    _entities.Update(entity);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

**In your code**

```
 using (var transaction = _table1Repository.BeginTransaction())
 {
     try
     {
         _table1Repository.Update(table1Rec);

         _table2Repository.Insert(table2Rec);

         transaction.Commit();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         transaction.Rollback();
        // some code...
     }
 }
```